# How to do ajax Post of one complex JSON object in a knockout observable array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, knockout.js

Can't quite figure out how to solve my current situation. I have a complex javascript objects representing an 'organization'. In the page, a list of these organizations are loaded up via ajax get request and pushed into a ko observable array, like so:

```
$.getJSON(apiBaseUrl + "?userId=" + userId, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function () {
        var dropdownOrg = new DropdownOrg();
        var org = new Organization();
        $.each(this, function (k, v) {
            if (k === "UserGuid") {
                org.userGuid = v;
            }
            if (k === "OrgId") {
                dropdownOrg.orgId = v;
                org.orgId = v;
            }
            if (k === "OrgName") {
                dropdownOrg.name = v;
                org.orgName = v;
            }
            if (k === "IsHiring") {
                org.isHiring = v;
            }
            if (k === "Blurb") {
                org.blurb = v;
            }
            if (k === "HqLocCity") {
                org.hqLocCity = v;
            }
            if (k === "HqLocCountry") {
                org.hqLocCountry = v;
            }
            if (k === "NumberOfEmployees") {
                org.numberOfEmployees = v;
                self.selectedEmployee(v);
            }
            if (k === "OrgImg") {
                org.orgImg = v;
            }
            if (k === "Ownership") {
                org.ownership = v;
                self.selectedOwnership(v);
            }
            if (k === "Website") {
                org.website = v;
            }
        });
        self.orgDdl.push(dropdownOrg);
        self.orgs.push(org);
    });
});
```

self.OrgDdl is an observable array that only holds enough data so I can switch which organization I am viewing on the page (visibility toggling). self.orgs is the ko observable array that is holding all the data i need to save via an ajax PUT. The organization object looks like this (beware, is ugly):

```
function Organization(userGuid,
orgId,
orgName,
orgImg,
isHiring,
blurb,
numberOfEmployees,
hqLocCity,
hqLocCountry,
website,
ownership) 
{
var self = this;
self.userGuid = userGuid;
self.orgId = orgId;
self.orgName = ko.observable(orgName);
self.isHiring = ko.observable(isHiring);
self.blurb = ko.observable(blurb);
self.numberOfEmployees = ko.observable(numberOfEmployees);
self.hsLocCity = ko.observable(hqLocCity);
self.hsLocCountry = ko.observable(hqLocCountry);
self.website = ko.observable(website);
self.ownership = ko.observable(ownership);
self.orgImg = ko.observable(orgImg);
}
```

Told you, pretty ugly, but I don't really know how to make that cleaner, and it binds alright, so good enough for now. In the current situation I have 3 organizations being loaded into the orgs observable array. In each of the organizations views I will be placing a button (haven't done it yet, need to figure this out first) that will take the currently visible org and post it.

I have a shell of a PUT request, but I am not sure how to get the current org that I am view out of the array.

```
 self.updateOrganization = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: apiBaseUrl + "?userId=" + userId,
        data: ko.toJSON(?????),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert('Error updating information, please try again!');
        }
    });
```

Any idea?

Comment: You could loop through the array that holds all of the organizations and find the one that matches some ID? Then call ko.toJSON() on that.

Comment: hey i just found this:self.selectedOrg.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        alert(newValue);
    }, self);  should do the trick. I will post working code if I can get it working..

Comment: any idea how to get .indexOf() on this object? I have the orgId, need to get the whole org object from the orgs array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
self.selectedOrgId.subscribe(function (currentOrgId) {
    //alert(currentOrgId);
    var org = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.orgs(), function (item) {
        if (currentOrgId == item.orgId) {
            return item;
        }
    });
    alert(ko.toJSON(org));
}, self);
```

So I can subscribe to changed to my selectedOrgId which gets updated each time I change my drop down list item. Then I can take that id in, use the ko.util.arrayFirst functions to find the item in my observable array that has that id.

Credit to: [this guy](http://www.adamthings.com/post/2013/08/26/find-element-observable-array-knockoutjs/)